# Login through iPhone facebook Graph API in drupal site

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, drupal, drupal-7

I am developing one application for iPhone , backend is drupal , now drupal 7 facebook sdk allows them to direct login into drupal site from facebook api , is there anykind of mechanism in iPhone facebook graph API ? , means suppose i am providing my FB credential to facebook graph api , and it will automatically login into drupal site , right now i am getting access token but , i want to do direct login as drupal 7 facebook sdk provides , please help me out , thanks in advance.